# Strip characters from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

All,

I need a little help with an SQL dilemma.  I have a table of data and one field can contain a string of multiple order codes.  Some of these codes get certain suffixes and prefixes removed.  Also, some of the individual codes are part of an "junk code" table, so I need to remove them from the string.  As an example, "%SBLYMER 8593SB= S8593" would need to be converted to "8593" because %SBLYMER is a junk code, I need to strip the SB= from 8593SB=, and I strip the S from S8593.  8593 then becomes duplicated and I just need to get the single value and update my original table with that string.

Another example would be "%36203SBX 4112SB= %%S4112 4112QDB=" needs to be updated to "%36203SBX 4112 4112QDB=".

I have a function and a procedure that achieves this goal; however, it takes about 5 minutes to run and I need to run this procedure as much as 100 times per day with different data sets and on two different columns of data.  Could anybody suggest a more efficient approach? It appears concatenating the separate codes back together takes the majority of time. Here's my procedure:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  STEP 12.5: Remove suffixes from the result_reflex_code column.      --
--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#convertReflexCodes') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP Table #convertReflexCodes
    END 
;
--  split the result_reflex_code items into separate records
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT  t2.result_code
                    , dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.Item) AS reflexCode
    FROM            compendium_8_utilization_temp as t1 INNER JOIN 
                        compendium_8_utilization_temp as t2 ON t1.util_id = t2.util_id
        CROSS Apply dbo.SplitStrings(t1.result_reflex_code, CHAR(10)) as f
    WHERE t2.result_code != ''
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.Item) FROM OERDB_Junk_Codes
                        WHERE dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.Item) = OERDB_Junk_Codes.TestCode)
)

--  reconcatenate the separate records into a temp table
SELECT DISTINCT
    result_code,                                        
    STUFF((                                                      
            SELECT CHAR(10) + u.reflexCode                                                     
            FROM CTE as u
            WHERE u.result_code = CTE.result_code                          
            ORDER BY u.reflexCode                                                        
            FOR xml path('')                                                
        ),1,1,'') as CPT_List
INTO #convertReflexCodes                                     
FROM CTE


--  update the final output table
UPDATE  compendium_8_utilization_temp
SET     result_reflex_code = cpt_List
FROM    compendium_8_utilization_temp INNER JOIN
            #convertReflexCodes ON compendium_8_utilization_temp.result_code = #convertReflexCodes.result_code

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  STEP 12.6: Remove suffixes from the order_entry_add_code column.    --
--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#convertOEACodes') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP Table #convertOEACodes
    END 
;
--  split the result_reflex_code items into separate records
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT  t2.result_code
                    , dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.item) AS reflexCode
    FROM            compendium_8_utilization_temp as t1 INNER JOIN 
                        compendium_8_utilization_temp as t2 ON t1.util_id = t2.util_id
        CROSS Apply dbo.SplitStrings(t1.order_entry_add_code, CHAR(10)) as f
    WHERE t2.result_code != ''
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.Item) FROM OERDB_Junk_Codes
                        WHERE dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.Item) = OERDB_Junk_Codes.TestCode)
)

--  reconcatenate the separate records into a temp table
SELECT DISTINCT
    result_code,                                        
    STUFF((                                                      
            SELECT CHAR(10) + u.reflexCode                                                     
            FROM CTE as u
            WHERE u.result_code = CTE.result_code                          
            ORDER BY u.reflexCode                                                        
            FOR xml path('')                                                
        ),1,1,'') as CPT_List
INTO #convertOEACodes                                     
FROM CTE

--  update the final output table
UPDATE  compendium_8_utilization_temp
SET     order_entry_add_code = cpt_List
FROM    compendium_8_utilization_temp INNER JOIN
            #convertOEACodes ON compendium_8_utilization_temp.result_code = #convertOEACodes.result_code
```

[example of WITH time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RRNR.jpg)

EDIT TO INCLUDE DATA

Here is a snippet of the junk code table:

```
    CREATE TABLE OERDB_Junk_Codes(
   jl_id    INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,TestCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2000,'%14742RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2001,'%14744RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2004,'%17222RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2005,'%35083RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2006,'%35092RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2007,'%35093RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2008,'%35094RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2009,'%35095RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2010,'%35096RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2011,'%35097RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2012,'%35098RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2013,'%35099RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2014,'%35100RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2015,'%35101RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2016,'%35084RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2017,'%35102RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2018,'%17223RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2019,'%17224RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2020,'%17225RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2021,'%17226RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2022,'%35085RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2023,'%35086RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2024,'%35087RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2025,'%35088RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2026,'%35089RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2027,'%35090RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2028,'%35091RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2029,'%17222');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2030,'%35083');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2031,'%35092');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2032,'%35093');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2033,'%35094');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2034,'%35095');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2035,'%35096');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2036,'%35097');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2037,'%35098');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2038,'%35099');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2039,'%35100');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2040,'%35101');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2041,'%35084');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2042,'%35102');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2043,'%17223');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2044,'%17224');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2045,'%17225');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2046,'%17226');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2047,'%35085');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2048,'%35086');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2049,'%35087');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2050,'%35088');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2051,'%35089');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2052,'%35090');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2053,'%35091');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (2054,'%91368RXE');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1925,'%8459RQEZ');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1926,'%381RQEZ');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1928,'%16912RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1929,'%16913RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1930,'%16914RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1931,'%16916RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1932,'%16917RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1933,'%16918RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1934,'%16919RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1935,'%16921RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1954,'%36204');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1955,'%%%SBDIQ');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1956,'%SBUARFL');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1957,'%AMMS');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1958,'%AMMSX');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1959,'%APAMPGC');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1960,'%APAMPGCX');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1961,'%34514RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1962,'%34517RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1963,'%38155RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1964,'%34515RAMD');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1965,'%16217RAPX');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1966,'%16213RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1967,'%16216RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1968,'%16218RAP');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1969,'%THMS');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1970,'%COMS');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1971,'%APOPIGCX');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1972,'%APPCPGC');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1973,'%APPCPGCX');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1974,'%APPRPGC');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1975,'%APPRPGCX');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1976,'%APOPIGC');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1977,'%APCOCGC');
INSERT INTO mytable(jl_id,TestCode) VALUES (1978,'%APCOCGCX');
```

Here's a snippet of the compendium data:

```
    CREATE TABLE compendium_8_utilization_temp(
   util_id              INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,seq                  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,order_code           VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,order_entry_add_code VARCHAR(8)
  ,result_code          INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,result_reflex_code   VARCHAR(274) NOT NULL
  ,type                 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (521570,1519,'2180',NULL,84021000,'%APMTDGC','TE');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (521571,1520,'2180',NULL,84021100,'%APMTQGC','TE');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (521572,1521,'2180',NULL,84021200,'%APOPIGC','TE');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (521577,1526,'2180',NULL,84021700,'%APPCPGC','TE');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (521578,1527,'2180',NULL,84021900,'%APPRPGC','TE');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (521579,1528,'2180',NULL,84022400,'%APETOGC','TE');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (522154,2788,'3020','SBCULHLD',30006415,'%SBCULI %SBNOCULI %SBNOCULI','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (522155,2789,'3020','SBCULHLD',30006515,'%SBCULI %SBNOCULI','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (522156,2790,'3020','SBCULHLD',30006700,'%SBNOCULI %SBCULI %SBNOCULI','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (522170,2796,'3020','SBCULHLD',30007900,'%SBNOCULI %SBCULI','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (522161,2797,'3020','SBCULHLD',30008900,'%SBCULI %SBNOCULI %SBNOCULI','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (544579,2810,'%SBCULI',NULL,75030100,'395SB= 395X=','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (523158,4394,'6462',NULL,55071600,'%35645SB %35645XCA S%35645','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (523240,4489,'6646',NULL,45054600,'%SBLYMER 8593SB= S8593','T');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (533290,16264,'90072',NULL,45060420,'%36209SBX 255SB= %IN3 37923SB= 34088SB=','TE');
INSERT INTO mytable(util_id,seq,order_code,order_entry_add_code,result_code,result_reflex_code,type) VALUES (533291,16277,'90073',NULL,45060420,'%36209SBX 4942SB= %IN4 16088SB=','TE');
```

Here's the fnTCSuffix function:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTCSuffix]
(
    @testCode nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue nvarchar(50)
    SELECT @returnValue = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @testCode like '%SB'   THEN    LEFT(@testCode, LEN(@testCode) - 2)
            WHEN @testCode like '%SB='  THEN    LEFT(@testCode, LEN(@testCode) - 3)
            WHEN @testCode like '%SBX=' THEN    LEFT(@testCode, LEN(@testCode) - 4)
            WHEN @testCode like '%SBX'  THEN    LEFT(@testCode, LEN(@testCode) - 3)
            WHEN @testCode like '%X='   THEN    LEFT(@testCode, LEN(@testCode) - 2)
            WHEN @testCode like 'S[%]%' THEN    RIGHT(@testCode, LEN(@testCode) -1)
            WHEN @testCode like 'S%' AND CONVERT(varchar(1),substring(@testCode, 2,1)) like '[1-9]' THEN RIGHT(@testCode, LEN(@testCode) -1)
            ELSE @testCode
        END 
    RETURN @returnValue 
END
```

And the splitStrings table-valued function:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings]
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
```

Comment: so how should we determine what is a junk code and what is a good code? what's the logic?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can't help much here because almost certainly you have issues in your functions. You have a scalar function fnTCSuffix which is a performance issue as scalar functions are just awful for performance. You also have a SplitStrings function here...this is also highly suspect as it seems that most people find a loop based splitter. If you post those functions, table definitions (including indexes), sample data and desired output you will find lots of help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Also, you're using your temp table in a join at the end, and the temp table has no index. If there are a lot of rows there, that could be pretty expensive. How many rows do you typically expect your temp table to hold? If it's a significant number, you can add a primary key index (clustered) to the temp table after you load it, and it might speed things up. But the performance problems could be hidden in your other functions as well.

Comment: Sadly, there's not a lot of logic to the junk codes.  It's an entire separate table with over 2000 codes.  Basically, if a code is "bill-only" it ends up in that table.

Comment: I too thought it might be the scalar functions, but the WITH table that contains both of those functions runs in about one second.  At the maximum, that temp table only contains around 650 records.  It's that darned STUFF query that seems to slow things down.

Comment: That's great. But we can't help you if we have nothing to work with. I would start with the scalar functions and also look at the splitter. I suspect this can be made to run super fast but we still don't have any actual details.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  I'm awaiting feedback from the boss of me to determine what data I can post since some of it is considered internal-use only and proprietary.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to devise a solution.  It's not elegant, but by breaking up the source table into smaller temp tables, the procedure runs in seconds rather than minutes.

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  STEP 12.5: Remove suffixes from the result_reflex_code column.      --
--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#convertReflexCodes') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP Table #convertReflexCodes
    END 

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#utilCodesWithReflexes') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP Table #utilCodesWithReflexes
    END             

SELECT DISTINCT   t2.order_code
                , t2.result_code
                , dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.item) AS reflexCode
INTO            #utilCodesWithReflexes
FROM            compendium_8_utilization_temp as t1 INNER JOIN 
                    compendium_8_utilization_temp as t2 ON t1.util_id = t2.util_id
    CROSS Apply dbo.SplitStrings(t1.result_reflex_code, CHAR(10)) as f
WHERE t2.result_code != '' AND LEN(t2.result_reflex_code) > 0

-- nullify any codes that are in the junk list
UPDATE  #utilCodesWithReflexes
SET     reflexCode = Null
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT TESTCODE 
                FROM OERDB_Junk_Codes 
                WHERE TestCode = reflexCode)

-- strip suffixes from the remaining codes
UPDATE  #utilCodesWithReflexes
SET     reflexCode = dbo.fnTCSuffix(reflexCode)
WHERE   reflexCode IS NOT NULL

--  concatenate the test codes back together            
SELECT DISTINCT
    order_code 
    ,result_code                                        
    ,STUFF((                                                      
            SELECT CHAR(10) + u.reflexCode                                                     
            FROM #utilCodesWithReflexes as u
            WHERE u.result_code = #utilCodesWithReflexes.result_code
                    AND u.order_code = #utilCodesWithReflexes.order_code                        
            ORDER BY u.reflexCode                                                        
            FOR xml path('')                                                
        ),1,1,'') as reflexCodes
INTO    #convertReflexCodes                                     
FROM    #utilCodesWithReflexes

--  update the output table
UPDATE  compendium_8_utilization_temp
SET     result_reflex_code = reflexCodes
FROM    compendium_8_utilization_temp INNER JOIN
            #convertReflexCodes ON compendium_8_utilization_temp.result_code = #convertReflexCodes.result_code  
            AND compendium_8_utilization_temp.order_code = #convertReflexCodes.order_code       


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  STEP 12.6: Remove suffixes from the order_entry_add_code column.    --
--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#convertOEACodes') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP Table #convertOEACodes
    END

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#utilCodesWithOEAC') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP Table #utilCodesWithOEAC
    END


SELECT DISTINCT   t2.order_code
                , t2.result_code
                , dbo.fnTCSuffix(f.item) AS reflexCode
INTO            #utilCodesWithOEAC
FROM            compendium_8_utilization_temp as t1 INNER JOIN 
                    compendium_8_utilization_temp as t2 ON t1.util_id = t2.util_id
    CROSS Apply dbo.SplitStrings(t1.order_entry_add_code, CHAR(10)) as f
WHERE t2.result_code != '' AND LEN(t2.order_entry_add_code) > 0


-- nullify any codes that are in the junk list
UPDATE  #utilCodesWithOEAC
SET     reflexCode = Null
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT TESTCODE 
                FROM OERDB_Junk_Codes 
                WHERE TestCode = reflexCode)


-- strip suffixes from the remaining codes
UPDATE  #utilCodesWithOEAC
SET     reflexCode = dbo.fnTCSuffix(reflexCode)
WHERE   reflexCode IS NOT NULL


--  concatenate the test codes back together            
SELECT DISTINCT
    order_code 
    ,result_code                                        
    ,STUFF((                                                      
            SELECT CHAR(10) + u.reflexCode                                                     
            FROM #utilCodesWithOEAC as u
            WHERE u.result_code = #utilCodesWithOEAC.result_code
                    AND u.order_code = #utilCodesWithOEAC.order_code                        
            ORDER BY u.reflexCode                                                        
            FOR xml path('')                                                
        ),1,1,'') as reflexCodes
INTO    #convertOEACodes                                     
FROM    #utilCodesWithOEAC

--  update the output table
UPDATE  compendium_8_utilization_temp
SET     order_entry_add_code = reflexCodes
FROM    compendium_8_utilization_temp INNER JOIN
            #convertOEACodes ON compendium_8_utilization_temp.result_code = #convertOEACodes.result_code    
            AND compendium_8_utilization_temp.order_code = #convertOEACodes.order_code
```